# Going back to XCode 4.1 after installing XCode 4.2 beta 7

Tags: xcode

I've installed XCode 4.2 beta but I realize I can't deploy applications on my iOS 3.1.3 device. The previous XCode 4.1 was able to, but it seems I can't install it back.

What I've tried so far:

- install XCode 4.1 directly on top of 4.2. XCode 4.2 persisted
- delete the Developer folder, install XCode 4.1. Nothing happened, altho the installation went thru

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this.  "Installing" XCode 4.1 on top of the 4.2 beta doesn't actually do anything other than creating a 4GB "Install Xcode" file in /Applications.  Running THAT shows a prompt that the newer version of XCode will be moved to /Developer-4.2 and the old version will be installed in /Developer.

I found the process confusing because I didn't realize right away that I was supposed to run /Applications/Install Xcode.

Comment: Yeah. I saw this too later on, but I thought it was some problem on my machine. Didn't realize this is the "normal" behavior ...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and had to run this in Terminal:

sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

This will remove your Development folder and the other bits around your system, so that you can install Xcode from scratch.

Comment: I've tried this now. Uninstalling... I'll try to se if Xcode 4.1 will install correctly and come back with an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

try to install it in the other directory ie. Developer/Xcode_old/ but then you have to run proper application(from the correct path).

I have currently both versions installed, so that's definitely can be done.

Comment: And how do I do that? All the Xcode installer asks me is on what HDD to install it, no path no nothing.

Comment: On the very next screen after the HDD screen. I mean the one you are selecting components that will be installed, you click on icon 'Developer' and choose 'Others' from the list

Comment: I've managed to install back the 4.1. Next time I'll try what you suggested in order to have both Xcode versions. But maybe I'll wait for the official release. I'll leave the DaveN's answer as the accepted answer for it is more close to what I was needing, but I'll give your answer a vote-up. Thank you!

Comment: Note that I tried installing multiple versions by specifying a different install directory but some things still went into /Developer (shark or other tools) instead of where I specified. To get around this I install to /Developer then rename to /Developer_3.2.5 and then create an alias to the whatever version I want to use name developer. From the Terminal prompt it is:

    `cd /;`
    `mv Developer Developer_3.2.5;`
    `ln -s Developer_3.2.5 Developer;`

(Might have to sudo these depending on permissions)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that I downloaded the 4.1 installer from Apple, but the 4.1 installer doesn't actually install XCode 4.1, it installs an installer for XCode 4.1 called "Install XCode"--BUT "Install XCode" already existed for the 4.2 install and it would not apparently overwrite it.

I renamed "Install XCode" to "Install XCode 4.2", reran the XCode 4.1 "installer" which installed a new "Install XCode", this time for 4.1.

(Who came up with this installer for an installer madness?)

I'm just ran the installer for XCode 4.1 (after mv'ing /Developer to /XCode-4.2) and it seems to have worked.